# Translating from Cocos2d to Cocos2d-X

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, translate

I am translating a piece of code from cococs2D to cocos2D-X. I came across the following lines that i cannot fathom out how to translate

```
 [spriteBg runAction:[CCSequence actions:sc,[CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:basketTimer_ selector:NSSelectorFromString([selectors objectAtIndex:0]) object:sprite], nil]];
```

Can someone please help me translate this to Cocos2d in Cocos2d-X ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: If you could tell me what you hope to achieve through this.. then I can help better.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
spriteBg->runAction::create(CCSequence::create(sc,CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(myMethod)),NULL));
```

In your code the myMethod is replaced by the selector at the index 0 of the "selectors" which I'm guessing is an array of the selectors or a dictionary or something like that.
and "sc" is a predefined action which is to be run on spriteBg.

Answer (score 0):

For cocos2d-x v 2.2.1:

NSSelectorFromString([selectors objectAtIndex:0] <- in cocos2d-x you can't create selector from string, so you must know function you want call, or keep selectors in container(but I never do this)

```
CCCalFuncO *call = CCCallFuncO::create(basketTimer_, callfuncO_selector(BasketTimerClass::BasketTimerMethod), sprite)
spriteBg->runAction(CCSequence::create(sc, call, NULL));
```

Every class in cocos2d-x and cocos2d-iphone have the same name, so you can easly find it in documentation: 
[CCSequence](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2.1/dc/d7d/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_sequence.html) [CCCalFuncO](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2.1/d9/d91/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_call_func_o.html#a0320ef0846c37b346526137a62ad692b)